# Selenium Chrome webdriver exception

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the webdriver instance in Java. I have run selenium in the background.

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 121 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'ARMac.home', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

My code looks like this

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/chromedriver");
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

     String link = "http://www.google.com";
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
            "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

The way how I run Selenium is

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -timeout=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the chrome webdriver location to your java call:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -timeout=20 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path-to\chromedriver.exe

If you decide to use the IE Driver as well, you will need to add it, like:

-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\path-to\IEDriverServer.exe